# Android FMX INDY SSL Works on debugging but not from PlayStore download

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, indy

I'm facing a weird Delphi Indy SSL problem. I developed an app for Android which connects to an Server with SSL encryption. I provided OpenSSL libraries and it works fine on debugging the device (Samsung A 3 2016). But when I upload the .aab file and download the app from the PlayStore (internal Test), my app is unable to load the SSL libraries. So I tested with different devices to reproduce the bug. Unfortunately it worked on all device I downloaded the app (32bit and 64bit). I'm stuck with these particular device where I cannot reproduce the unable to load SSL Library mistake.

```
    Successful tested devices 
     - Samsung S4 Mini (32bit)
     - Samsung S7 Mini 
     - Sony XPeria XA (64Bit)
     - Sony XPeria XZ1 Compact (
     - Huawei P30 (64Bit)

Unsuccessful tested devices
 - Samsung A3 2016 (32bit)
  => this device is not able to load the SSL Libraries I provide
```

here is the Code I use to set the path depending from the OS and CPU

```
{$region 'Android'}
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
    {$IFDEF CPU64BITS}
      FAppPath := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath,'bit64');
      MemoText := '64 bit SSL libs: ' + FAppPath ;
      Synchronize(doMemoAddLine);
    {$ELSE}
      FAppPath := TPath.GetDocumentsPath ;
      MemoText := '32 bit SSL libs: ' + FAppPath ;
      Synchronize(doMemoAddLine);
    {$ENDIF}
    IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(FAppPath);
    MemoText := 'IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(' + FAppPath +')' ;
    Synchronize(doMemoAddLine);
    MemoText := WhichFailedToLoad;
    Synchronize(doMemoAddLine);
  {$ENDIF}
  {$endregion}
```

Comment: Are you deploying the OpenSSL `.so` files with your app? Are you calling Indy's `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function at program startup to tell Indy where to load the `.so` files from? What does Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function report after the loading fails?

Comment: Hello Remy, I read several from you and in my Code I’m calling the setLibPath function at startup, also I deploy me lib.so files, otherwise the other devices wouldn’t work either. How do I call WhichFailedToLoad() Function? I tried something like Memo1.Lines.add(WhichFailedToLoad); I guess it is not correct.

Comment: you can't call `WhichFailedToLoad()` until after Indy has attempted to load OpenSSL. By default, Indy does not load OpenSSL until it is actually needed. Unless you explicitly tell Indy to load the library by calling either `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.Load()` or `IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary()` directly in your own code.

Comment: Good to know. I‘ll implement this code for future debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem, I was using an older OpenSSL Library. I only deployed a newer library and it worked. Case closed